# Getting print messages from stored procedure along with rows affected in correct order

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I want to get `Print` result along with current number of rows affected by that particular query in stored procedure.

Currently, I am using `StatementCompleted` property to get the output.

```
insert into SprocParam values(@SprocId, @ParamName, @ParamType, @IsNullable, @Description);
print 'this is a test output'

select * from SprocParam;
```

My C# code goes like this:

```
....
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

conn.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(myConnection_InfoMessage);
command.StatementCompleted += sqlCommand_StatementCompleted;     
command.ExecuteScalar();
.....

static void sqlCommand_StatementCompleted(object sender, StatementCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     SprocController.executionMessage += e.RecordCount + " row(s) affected \n";
}

void myConnection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    SprocController.executionMessage += e.Message;
}
```

Now I get my answer for each query separately. But I want my answer like this:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
this is a test output
(21 row(s) affected)
```

I am not able to retrieve these print messages in their natural order as coded in the stored procedure.

Output which I am getting :

```
(1 row(s) affected)
(21 row(s) affected)
this is a test output
```

The stored procedure can't be changed. I can only change my C# code.

Please help!

Comment: what's the output you get?

Comment: (1 row(s) affected)
(21 row(s) affected)

Comment: Please Answer anyone !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the solution:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true; // triggering informational messages
```

followed by:

```
// for getting the rowsAffected by each statement individually to generate executionMessage
static void sqlCommand_StatementCompleted(object sender, StatementCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     SprocController.executionMessage += (e.RecordCount.ToString() + " row(s) affected " +  "\n");
}

// for getting the print Messages whenever an informational message occur at connection
static void myConnection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e1)
{
     SprocController.executionMessage += (e1.Message.ToString() + "\n"); 
}
```

All messages will be received correctly in their natural order

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the [`InfoMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) event on your `SqlConnection` object to receive the messages from `print` statements.

Comment: I did that already but then i get the following output : (1 row(s) affected)

(21 row(s) affected)this is a test output

Comment: I am not getting the order in which they are written in stored procedure

Comment: @Prakhar Please update the question with a (short) re-create to make it easy to test what is going on.

Comment: @Prakhar There are three statements that will give a row count in your SQL, but only two outputs: something else is going on. Could it be that you are missing the result from the `delete`?

Comment: sorry check the procedure now

Comment: @Prakhar I cannot answer  usefully if you keep changing the question. In debugging the details are critically important, if they are wrong then you'll get wrong answers.